# Replacing a string in Sublime

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I'd like to replace this
`y[100]` with this `Ith(y,100)` in Sublime3.
I've got the regular expression `\by[\d+]` in find what and `Ith(y,$1)` in replace with, but it doesn't work. It finds what to replace correctly but just replaces it with `Ith(y, )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pick the `\d+` inside `()` to capture in group(`$1`)

```
\by[(\d+)]
```

Also, you may need to to escape the `[` and `]` characters here.

```
\by\[(\d+)\]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to capture the data you want to backreference: to do that you have to use unescaped parenthesis `(...)`, ie capturing groups. Also, `[...]` are character classes, a special character in regex that you need to escape.

Try replacing

```
\by\[(\d+)\]
```

with

```
Ith(y, \1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the special characters and capture the number in a capturing group group. Try this regex:

```
\by\[(\d+)]\b
```

And replace with

```
Ith(y, $1)
```

Online explanation and demonstration: http://regex101.com/r/nX3yJ9